# DSE 4.8 Solr deep paging performace issue

Tags: datastax-enterprise, solr4

I've just have a question about Solr deep-paging performance. I have installed DSE 4.8 cluster (Cassandra + Solr) and the things are going well until we hit some issues with depp-paging. Solr performs well searching and indexing data but we hit a serious lack of performace doing deep-paging. 
The database has 110GB of data per each node (4 in total; 2 x C* + 2 x Solr), Solr resolves the searches very quick and the paging through the result set (20 rows per page), however the problem comes when I try to get an entire result set of 3,000 or 5,000 rows from the database. For this last scenario I am using the deep page technique and unfortunately i can't fetch more than 1000 rows every ~10 secs. Is there any chance to improve deep page performance on DSE Solr?.

Cheers

Comment: How much data are we talking in terms of bytes

Comment: Ok, the table is quite big (240 columns) but I am selecting only 2 float columns of it.The weirdest thing is that if I run the query for a second time, query goes very quickly and thus I presume the caching mechanism is working ok, but the first hit of the query seems very heavy for the database sin somehow. I'd appreciate any feedback on this. Cheers

Comment: Are you using fq? Sounds like you need to tune your filter cache. I recommend you try setting autowarming to 90% in the solrconfig.xml

Comment: Yes, I am using fq. I am using this doc page a reference: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Pagination+of+Results 
Ok, I'll try to set up autowarming as you suggest. Thank you. I'll let you know

Comment: Make sure you use the new DSE filter cache not the default solr one.

Comment: ok, fortunately the picture has dramatically changed. I made three changes;increased the dse cache watermarks to 1024MB. setup the parallel large C* reads (http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchParallelRetr.html) and increase the number of executor threads to 6. It seems pretty good results so far but I have to analyse the performance in more depth.

Comment: :) thought it would. All about knowing the right levers to tune.